# how do i display id on page using php

Tags: php, content-management-system

On [THIS PAGE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/list.php?id=FREE), I have the word `"category ="` before my campaigns.

My problem is: I am unable to find the code that can display the page id as shown in the  url.

How can I get this to echo the page id as shown in the URL? to say `"category = FREE"`.

can someone please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "category = ", htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any URL parameter can be retrieved using `$_GET["param_name"]`, in your case: `$_GET["id"]`. You can save that as a variable, or echo it right away.

Comment: i tried that but it did not work.